# Oracle Invalid Number Error When Inserting

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I am trying to run insert-select query. But whatever I do, I get "Invalid Number" error.

My query is like this;

```
INSERT INTO banka_odeme (banka_id, banka_ad, banka_tutar, aciklama, banka_ismi)
SELECT 
    (SELECT MAX(banka_id) + 1 FROM banka_odeme),
    w.first_name || ' ' || w.last_name,
    TO_NUMBER(w.total),
    TO_NUMBER(w.id),
    'SiPay'
FROM 
    woo_orders w 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM banka_odeme WHERE banka_odeme.aciklama = TO_NUMBER(w.id));
```

My table structure is like this; (Please check the image links below)

[Banka_Odeme Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyh9G.png)

[Woo_Orders Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU6vb.png)

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help :))

I've tried every possible query combinations and it still gives the same error. :(

Comment: please read [wha not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and [why should i provide a minimal reproducible example in sql](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and edit your question

Comment: Don't know. I'd remove all those `TO_NUMBER` on columns that are already numeric. `TO_NUMBER` is a string function that tries to convert a string into a number. If invoked on a number, I suppose that Oracle must turn the number into a string first in order to convert it back to a number. This can cause problems, when for instance the default is to convert a number into a string with thousand separators, because as far as I remember such number strings cannot be converted to number without an explicit format.

Comment: The only obvious thing is that `banka_odeme.aciklama` is being implicitly converted to a number to compare with `w.id` - so if that contains strings that don't represent numbers (at least with your session NLS settings) then you will get that error. If that is the correct column then you can see if it contains such values. Though you shouldn't store numbers as strings, of course.

Comment: If you can modify your table structure, change your datatypes so that numeric values are stored in number fields, not in varchar2 fields. Then you won't have to worry about running into this with your queries.

Comment: That answer by MT0 made it for me. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `w.total` and `w.id` are already numbers - don't use `TO_NUMBER` on them.
- Don't use `(SELECT MAX(banka_id) + 1 FROM banka_odeme)` to generate the next number in a sequence, use a proper `SEQUENCE`.
- `banka_odeme.aciklama` is a string and `w.id` is a number. When you compare them either convert the string to a number `TO_NUMBER(banka_odeme.aciklama) = w.id`(but if it's always convertible to a numeric then why are you storing it as a string) or convert the number to a string `banka_odeme.aciklama = TO_CHAR(w.id)`.
- If you want to merge one table into another then you can use a `MERGE` statement.

So:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(200);
  v_id  BANKA_ODEME.BANKA_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(banka_id) + 1
  INTO   v_id
  FROM   banka_odeme;

  v_sql := 'CREATE SEQUENCE banka_odeme__banka_id__seq START WITH ' || v_id;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
/
```

Then:

```
MERGE INTO banka_odeme b
USING woo_orders w
ON (b.aciklama = TO_CHAR(w.id))
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (
    banka_id,
    banka_ad,
    banka_tutar,
    aciklama,
    banka_ismi
  ) VALUES (
    banka_odeme__banka_id__seq.NEXTVAL,
    w.first_name || ' ' || w.last_name,
    w.total,
    TO_CHAR(w.id),
    'SiPay'
  );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qzEHzXfo)

Comment: Thank you so much MT0! I've been trying to deal with it for 2 days and you completedly killed it. Have a great day!